# I seem to be doing everything right for my simple counter program, but nothing happens when i run the program on the command line

Tags: java

I made a simple counter program. It counts to 100. Here it is.

```
class counter {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int count;

    count = 0;

    for (count = 0; count <= 99; count++) {
        System.out.println("count " + count);
    }
    if (count == 100) {
        System.out.println("final count " + count);
    }
}
}
```

When I compile and run the .class file, nothing is printed out, even though I used `System.out.println()`. Maybe its obvious, but I can't tell what I did wrong.

Comment: What command are you using to compile, and what command to run it?

Comment: The code works as expeced. See on [TIO](https://tio.run/##hU3LDoJADLzvVzScIESCR4J8BUfjofLK4tIlbCExxG9f1wX1ZJwe2mk7Mz0ueNBjQ319s7ZSaAwMKGkVYpyvSlZgGNm1RcvaX8KSJ0kd4NSZ8yWCVYCDJIZKz8S58NzPUEC681ZPEH6X@/1UQJbtJI7fXi@Ud8PNkOiZk9HFsaIw2DQBxJsgyv33Y8tvP/YFHNP0n1crCRX8cnRl7RM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is correct.

Put it in a file called **counter.java**

**Compile it**

```
$ javac counter.java
```

**Run it**

```
$ java counter
```

**Output**

```
count 0
count 1
count 2
count 3
count 4
count 5
count 6
count 7
count 8
count 9
count 10
count 11
count 12
count 13
count 14
count 15
count 16
count 17
count 18
count 19
count 20
count 21
count 22
count 23
count 24
count 25
count 26
count 27
count 28
count 29
count 30
count 31
count 32
count 33
count 34
count 35
count 36
count 37
count 38
count 39
count 40
count 41
count 42
count 43
count 44
count 45
count 46
count 47
count 48
count 49
count 50
count 51
count 52
count 53
count 54
count 55
count 56
count 57
count 58
count 59
count 60
count 61
count 62
count 63
count 64
count 65
count 66
count 67
count 68
count 69
count 70
count 71
count 72
count 73
count 74
count 75
count 76
count 77
count 78
count 79
count 80
count 81
count 82
count 83
count 84
count 85
count 86
count 87
count 88
count 89
count 90
count 91
count 92
count 93
count 94
count 95
count 96
count 97
count 98
count 99
final count 100
```

Comment: thanks! I wasn't compiling running it correctly, my bad.